# Built-in function goes undefined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a laravel project up and running in my localhost. but when i upload all files to the server. it gives me error: The built-in function in laravel goes undefined.

> FatalErrorException in Encrypter.php line 71: Call to undefined
>   function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_encrypt()

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should edit `php.ini` file and uncomment an extension. For example, change this:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

to this:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: I could not find that `php.ini` file in server. where it actually is?

Answer (score 1):

just edit php.ini and uncomment this like

;extension=php_openssl.dll
chnaged to 
extension=php_openssl.dll

Comment: I could not find that `php.ini` file in server. where it actually is?

Comment: create custom php.ini file

Comment: @micky if you can access a terminal on the remote server run `php -i | grep php.ini` (or if it's windows the equivalent on windows). It should tell you where the loaded php.ini is located (if any)